# Case when in where clause Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, switch-statement, where-clause

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM table 
WHERE t1.name||t1.lastname||... ilike ANY (ARRAY['%Muller%'])  
OR t1.name||t1.lastname||... ilike all (ARRAY['%Muller%'])
```

I would like to add CASE WHEN so my query is:

```
 SELECT *  
 FROM table 
 WHERE t1.name||t1.lastname||... ilike  CASE WHEN TRUE IS TRUE THEN  
 ANY (ARRAY['%Muller%'])  ELSE all (ARRAY['%Muller%'])  END
```

so i could avoid copy and pasting the whole fields again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LATERAL` to avoid concatentating multiple times:

```
SELECT *  
FROM table t1, LATERAL(SELECT t1.name||t1.lastname||...) s(c)
WHERE s.c ilike ANY (ARRAY['%Muller%'])  
  OR s.c ilike ALL (ARRAY['%Muller%'])
```

Comment: What if i have join between 5 tables and i add this LATERAL join will it affect on the performance somehow?

Comment: @MoHalem No it shouldn't, just place `LATERAL` after last `JOIN`